# I want to upload files from different file inputs in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js, sails-skipper

```
await sails.upload(inputs.logo);

await sails.upload(inputs.thumbnail);
```

I use sails-hook-uploads. Only the first incoming file (logo, in my case) is uploaded and for thumbnail, it shows this message.

> Upstream (file upload: `thumbnail`) emitted an error: { Error: EMAXBUFFER: An upstream (`thumbnail`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.

Is there anyway I can fix that or alternative simple way to upload files from different file inputs in sailsjs?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are uploading files one by one, try using uploadOne.

```
await sails.uploadOne(inputs.logo);

await sails.uploadOne(inputs.thumbnail);
```

Comment: I can't use it either. Only the logo is uploaded and the thumbnail emitted an error. :(